# Cannot Create New Folder In My Laptop

Tags: windows-10, windows-8, laptop, installation

I have my Windows 8.1 laptop in my home and Windows 10 laptop at the office.
After I installed 360 Security, NodeJS and Composer to both laptops I could not create a New folder with both laptop.
 What is the possible reason about it?
Is the sofware not compatible? or is their an error with my registry?
 I'm looking for solution right now because I just copy and paste an empty folder for me to add new folder.

Comment: Where do yo want the new folder? Some locations are always forbidden, some are restricted to Administrator...

Comment: @DrMoishe Pippik when I right click in desktop and click new folder and in windows explorer at New Group at the home tab nothing happens..

Comment: Try to roll back using system restore to the point before you installed the software. Take notes when reinstalling which breaks it.

Comment: I also have an idea about that but is their any alternative rather than doing that? I heard about "New Folder Fix" using registry and I still googling about it, do have one? @Louis

Comment: Right-click start to launch PowerShull or the command prompt, and you can use mkdir: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GfHQ.png

If that doesn't work something is seriously wrong and you still want to roll back.

Comment: Thanks for the your effort @Louis I take your answer as my alternative next time. But right now I got my own answer. Please see my answer below and visit the link of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EUREKA!! After a lot of time googling, reading Microsoft forums and looking for different websites and more time or hard work copying and pasting blank folder, I got this **solution**.  Based from the article I've read, there is conflict between the **registry file**. Fixing the problem was by using the registry file that has code to access Windows Registry Editor and make some changes with it.  The registry file that fixed my problem is located at my github account  https://github.com/aice09/Things-To-Remember/blob/master/NewFolderFix.reg . I hope this will help you too, same as I am.

NewFolderFix.reg

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}]
@="CLSID_ExecuteFolder"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}\InProcServer32]
@="ExplorerFrame.dll"
"ThreadingModel"="Apartment"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\New]
@="{D969A300-E7FF-11d0-A93B-00A0C90F2719}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder]
@="Folder"
"EditFlags"=hex:d2,03,00,00
"FullDetails"="prop:System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemNameDisplay;System.ItemType;System.Size"
"ThumbnailCutoff"=dword:00000000
"TileInfo"="prop:System.Title;System.PropGroup.Description;System.ItemType"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\DefaultIcon]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,00,68,00,\
  65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore]
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000022
"ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000021

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\explore\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
  00,65,00,2c,00,2f,00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,\
  2c,00,25,00,4c,00,00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open]
"MultiSelectModel"="Document"
"BrowserFlags"=dword:00000010
"ExplorerFlags"=dword:00000012

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\open\command]
@=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,74,00,25,\
  00,5c,00,45,00,78,00,70,00,6c,00,6f,00,72,00,65,00,72,00,2e,00,65,00,78,00,\
  65,00,20,00,2f,00,73,00,65,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,61,00,74,00,65,00,2c,00,2f,\
  00,69,00,64,00,6c,00,69,00,73,00,74,00,2c,00,25,00,49,00,2c,00,25,00,4c,00,\
  00,00
"DelegateExecute"="{11dbb47c-a525-400b-9e80-a54615a090c0}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ColumnHandlers\{F9DB5320-233E-11D1-9F84-707F02C10627}]
@="PDF Column Info"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\BriefcaseMenu]
@="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{474C98EE-CF3D-41f5-80E3-4AAB0AB04301}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{a2a9545d-a0c2-42b4-9708-a0b2badd77c8}]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\DragDropHandlers\{BD472F60-27FA-11cf-B8B4-444553540000}]
@=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\BriefcasePage]
@="{85BBD920-42A0-1069-A2E4-08002B30309D}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shellex\PropertySheetHandlers\Offline Files]
@="{7EFA68C6-086B-43e1-A2D2-55A113531240}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew]
"Directory"=""
"IconPath"=hex(2):25,00,53,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,52,00,6f,00,6f,00,\
  74,00,25,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,73,\
  00,68,00,65,00,6c,00,6c,00,33,00,32,00,2e,00,64,00,6c,00,6c,00,2c,00,33,00,\
  00,00
"ItemName"="@shell32.dll,-30396"
"MenuText"="@shell32.dll,-30317"
"NonLFNFileSpec"="@shell32.dll,-30319"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\ShellNew\Config]
"AllDrives"=""
"IsFolder"=""
"NoExtension"=""
```

Comment: Welcome to superuser: While this may answer the question it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation why your solution works with detail and an easy to follow instructions, Please take a couple of minutes and read:- superuser.com/help .Answering: superuser.com/help/how-to-answer, again welcome to superuser.Thankyou

Comment: Okay I got it. thge code for fixing registry file are here above @mic84

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you restore your computer to factory default, and try creating a folder before installing these applications. Normally, it will not fail. If it still fails in this situation, check for bad sectors in your hard drive.
Otherwise, the suspect will be the applications you install. The primary suspect may be 360 Security. Install NodeJS, Composer and 360 one by one, and try creating a folder after installing each software.
Plus, make sure that you're not doing this in a read-only folder or disk.

Comment: Thanks for the your answer @Aurus Huang I take your answer as my alternative next time. But right now I got my own answer. Please see my answer above and visit the link of the file.